# Within Mathematica, how to export the output of python code to the Mathematica expression?

Tags: python, external-calls

I run some Python code in the  `external code cell` as following:

[image]

The above Python code produced the `result` (as shown with red [1] in the screenshot), which is a list of squart of i.

Then, I want to analyze the `result` within Mathematica environment. Out of my expectation, the `result` shown as not defined (as shown with red [2] in the screenshot).

### My Question

How can I export the output `result` of Python to Mathematica computational enviroment? (So that I can further analyze the data in Mathematica)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Even if the session was still open</strike> `External code cell` will be open after executing, you can't use the same variable name you'd defined in the external session, inside Mathematica. Let me introduce you to [`ExternalValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalValue.html).

```
(* start a python session *)
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];


(* run your code using the defined session *)
ExternalEvaluate[session, "import math
result=[math.sqrt(i) for i in range(10)]"];


(* get the value from the session *)
ExternalValue[session, "result"]

(*Out: {0., 1., 1.41421, 1.73205, 2., 2.23607, 2.44949, 2.64575, 2.82843, 3.} *)


(* terminate the session *)
DeleteObject[session]
```

Also, you can use this workaround but it has its limitations:

```
result = ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import math
[math.sqrt(i) for i in range(10)]"];

result
(*Out: {0., 1., 1.41421, 1.73205, 2., 2.23607, 2.44949, 2.64575, 2.82843, 3.} *)
```

Note that if you use the `print` statement in python, this workaround doesn't work. `result` value will be `Null`.

#### Update 1

You can stay in the `External code cell`:

```
result = ExternalValue[ExternalEvaluate`GetDefaultExternalSession["Python"], "result"]
```

Comment: I think it’s important to note why the the `result` value would be `Null` when using a `print` statement. (Because the output of `Print` is `Null`, from my understanding)

Comment: Inspired by your solution, I find another workaround with `External Code Cell`.

Comment: Note the `ExternalValue` have [two usages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6ySZ.png), but you just use the second. As my guess, the first usage should be `ExternalValue["Python", "result"]`. But it's error....

Comment: @yode I agree with you. It's probably because it's still experimental, we see such behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by your solution, I find another workaround with External Code Cell:

[image]

Comment: Ideally I would expect _Mathematica_ to have inline external code cell. (We already have Ctrl+= for inline free-form, and Ctrl+4 for inline $\LaTeX$, why not more? ) OK, I know the external evaluation functionality is still EXPERIMENTAL…

Comment: @xzczd inline $\LaTeX$?.. I get an underscript box instead in Mathematica 12 and earlier...

Comment: @Ruslan It's new in 12.2 :) .