# How to assign the value to the mma variable when use the ExternalSession?

Tags: external-calls

Of course, I can use the this code:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
mmaVar1 = ExternalEvaluate[session, "a=[3,6,4];a"]
```

> {3, 6, 4}

Then I can get a MMA variable `mmaVar1`, its name is assigned by *Python*. But I have to say it hard to write python code in a string line. So I like typing a <kbd>></kbd> key into *DefaultPythonSession*:

[image]

But **how to get the value of `a` in the *DefaultPythonSession* and assign to a MMA variable?** This is my current method:

- Find the order of the *DefaultPythonSession* by `ExternalSessions[]`:
  [image]
- Then

  ```
  mmaVar2 = ExternalEvaluate[ExternalSessions[][[2]], "a"]
  ```

Dirty solution...

Comment: Maybe `SelectFirst[ExternalSessions["Python"], #["Name"] === "DefaultPythonSession" &]` make it less dirty ;)

Comment: Even better ```ExternalEvaluate`GetDefaultExternalSession["Python"]```

Comment: @BenIzd Magic!!!!

Comment: @BenIzd Do you mind to add an answer? I think it can help to read for the following user

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/250259/1871

Comment: @yode You didn't let me write comment. Astonished by your speed :D

Comment: @BenIzd It is a awesome solution, which is better than all answers in that link given by  xzczd

Comment: Thanks for your kind words, I think that post has some differences from yours, there, the person wants to directly use the session's variable without knowing (I guess) that there are separate, here your main point was to find the default session in a clean matter ;) Even though I wrote one of the answers in the link, I really don't know the difference between `ExternalEvaluate` and `ExternalValue`. Maybe that should be the next question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get `DefaultPythonSession` directly by:

```
ExternalEvaluate`GetDefaultExternalSession["Python"]
```

or if you prefer using `ExternalSessions` by:

```
SelectFirst[ExternalSessions["Python"], #["Name"] === "DefaultPythonSession" &]
```

You should also note, that starting fresh Mathematica, will not start a python session automatically, so if you didn't start one, the first method return unevaluated command while in the second method, you have the option to return whatever you want (default is `Missing["NotFound"]`).